# Octopus Deploy Tentacle crash after trying to deploy package

Tags: devops, octopus-deploy

when trying to deploy a package from Octopus Server to Octopus Tentacle, tentacle suddenly crashes with this info in logs:

`` 10 INFO  [] [RunningScript] [Read Lock] [no locks] Trying to acquire lock.
10 FATAL  Unhandled AppDomain exception occurred: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
System.ArgumentNullException
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.TryAdd(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Octopus.Shared.Scripts.ScriptIsolationMutex.ScriptIsolationMutexReleaser.EnterReadLock()
   at Octopus.Shared.Scripts.ScriptIsolationMutex.ScriptIsolationMutexReleaser.EnterLock()
   at Octopus.Shared.Scripts.RunningScript.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.TryAdd(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Octopus.Shared.Scripts.ScriptIsolationMutex.ScriptIsolationMutexReleaser.EnterReadLock()
   at Octopus.Shared.Scripts.ScriptIsolationMutex.ScriptIsolationMutexReleaser.EnterLock()
   at Octopus.Shared.Scripts.RunningScript.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() ``

Many thanks,
Pawel

Comment: What versions are you running?

Comment: I'm using Octopus 3.14.15 and Octopus Server is on the same VPS instance as Octopus Tentacle (version 3.14.159)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by reinstalling everything with default settings.